# "Глаз-алмаз", - откуда пошло это выражение?

Tags: фразеология

Глаз - алмаз! Говорят о внимательном человеке. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так говорят и о человеке, который на глаз определяет правильность чего-л (напр., точность строительной конструкции).
В любом случае, согласен, это "похвала глазу".

Почему возник именно алмаз? 
Предыдущие ответы правильно говорят о ценности алмаза, это и делает его уместным для похвалы.
Но это не главное.

Главное, почему народ выбрал алмаз: потому что в рифму!

Сравните: Глаз -- изумруд!

не катит...

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны, алмаз - чистый, прозрачный камень, а прозрачность и ясность - это характеристики и отличного зрения, и светлого ума.

С другой стороны, зрение очень важно для человека, его надо беречь, как драгоценный камень алмаз.

Comment: Можно добавить, что алмаз можно считать воплощением совершенства, так как его считают царем камней,  самым дорогим  ювелирным камнем.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что тут выражение имеет отношение к обработке камней. Это дело (а особенно обработку алмазов) доверяли только самым внимательным мастерам. Отсюда и значение.

Есть о глазах и внимательности еще выражения: "видно невооруженным глазом", "на глазок" и др.